# How to make a dictionary of dictionaries with same keys in a loop

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

Hello i'm new to python and i'm trying to make a dictionary that can contain multiple dictionaries (depending on how many the user wants) and each dictionary has the same keys as the previous one. with an output similar to this :

```
{0: {'Name': 'test1', 'Matiere': ['algo','python'], 'Notes': [[11,12],[15,13]}, 
 1: {'Name': 'test2', 'Matiere': ['algo'], 'Notes': [[11]]}}
```

but what i'm getting is that the values of the 2nd dictionary are overwriting the first one's and i'm left with an output like this :

```
{0: {'Name': 'test2', 'Matiere': ['algo'], 'Notes': [[11]}}, 
 1: {'Name': 'test2', 'Matiere': ['algo'], 'Notes': [[11]]}}
```

Here's my code :

```
def ajout():
    TS = int(input("Donner le nombre d'etudiants: "))
    tmp=[]
    for i in range(TS):
        Student['Name']=input(f"Donner le nom de L'etudiant n{i+1}: ")
        x=int(input("Donner le nombre de matieres : "))
        for j in range(x):
            tmp.append(input(f"Donner la matiere n{j+1}: "))
        Student['Matiere']=tmp
        tmp=[]
        tmp1=[]
        for j in range(len(Student['Matiere'])):
            y=int(input(f"Donner le nombre de notes du {Student['Matiere'][j]}: "))
            for k in range(y):
                tmp.append(int(input(f"Donner la note n{k+1}: ")))
            tmp1.append(tmp)
            tmp=[]
            Student['Notes']=tmp1
        print(Student)
        Students[i]={}
        Students[i]=Student
    print(Students)
ajout()
```

What Can I change to make it not overwrite the values, but instead have different values depending on what the user types.

PS : here's an image of the

[image: Code's execution]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you initialized `Student` outside of `ajout`' scope.

Hence, each time you do `Students[i]=Student` the same variable is added to the dict, erasing the new one you instantiate with `Students[i]={}`. As `Student` is always the same underlying dict structure, each elements in `Students` are actually referencing only on dict. This also explain why doing `Student['whatever'] = ...`  is modifying every element of `Students`.

Try inserting `Student = {}` somewhere at the beginning of `ajout` ;)
On a side note, there is few useless `tmp=[]`, you only need one here !